# How to see if a user has posted before, and if so, highlight his past posts?

Tags: php, css

I have a simple blog site for school and I need help with it. I need it so that if a user, that has posted before submits a posts, then those posts he made, currently and previously will be highlighted. I know I need someway of checking to see if that user is in my database but not sure how to go about it. Thank you in advance. I also can post my css or html form if needed.

Thanks

Here is my PHP

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('EST');
$date_posted = date('h:i:s Y-m-d');
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="post.css" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Daily Dorm News</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Your Daily Dorm News Post! </h1>
<div id="container"> <?php if ( isset($_GET['name']) and preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/", $_GET['name']) ) {

    echo $_GET['name'];

} else {

    echo "You entered an invalid name!\n";

}

?><br>


Your email address is: <?php if ( isset($_GET['email']) and preg_match("/.+@.+\..+/i", $_GET['email']) ) {

    echo $_GET['email'];

} else {

    echo "You didn't enter a proper email address!\n";

}
?><br>
You Posted : <?php if ( isset($_GET['message']) and preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/", $_GET['message']) ) {

    echo $_GET['message'];

} else {

    echo "The message is not valid! The message box was blank or you entered invalid symbols!\n";

}
?>

This event happened :<?php echo $_GET["date"]; ?><br>


</div>
<?php
/* [INFO/CS 1300 Project 3] index.php
 * Main page for our app.
 * Shows all previous posts and highlights the current user's post, if any.
* Includes a link to form.php if user wishes to create and submit a post.
*/

require('wall_database.php');

// Fetching data from the request sent by form.php  
$name = strip_tags($_REQUEST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_REQUEST['email']);
$message = strip_tags($_REQUEST['message']);
$date = strip_tags($_REQUEST['date']);

$is_valid_post = true;
// Checking if a form was submitted
if (isset($_REQUEST['name'])){
 // Fetching data from the request sent by form.php  
$name = strip_tags($_REQUEST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_REQUEST['email']);
$message = strip_tags($_REQUEST['message']);
$date = strip_tags($_REQUEST['date']);  
 // Saving the current post, if a form was submitted
 $post_fields = array();
 $post_fields['name'] = $name;
 $post_fields['email'] = $email;
 $post_fields['message'] = $message;
 $post_fields['date'] = $date;
 $success_flag = saveCurrentPost($post_fields);

}

//Fetching all posts from the database
$posts_array = getAllPosts();

require('header.php');
?>
   <p><a href="form.php">Submit a Post</a></p>

   <?php
   if(isset($name)) {
     echo "<h3>Thanks ".$name." for submitting your post.</h3>";
   }
   ?>

   <p>Here are all the posts we have received.</p>
   <ul id="posts_list">
   <div id="posts">
   <?php

   // Looping through all the posts in posts_array
   $counter = 1;

   foreach(array_reverse($posts_array) as $post){
     $name = $post['name'];
     $email = $post['email'];
     $message = $post['message'];
     $date = $post['date'];

     if ($counter % 2==1)
       $li_class = "float-left";
     else
       $li_class = "float-right";


        echo '<div class=post>';
        echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.'</span> wrote a post.</h3></li>';
        echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.' email is: '.$email.'</span></h3></li>';
        echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.' wrote '.$message.'</span> wrote a post.</h3></li>';
        echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>This event occured on '.$date_posted.'</span></h3></li>';
        echo '</div>';
   }
   ?>
   </ul>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll either need to:

1. Create a log in. Upon creating a new post, record it in the database. Check the records the next time the user posts. If a record exists, do what you want with the style
2. Check it against the email address if you don't want to create a login system. This method is prone to abuse errors, etc.,

Either way, you need to track some unique identifier.

Comment: id rather do Check it against the email address if you don't want to create a login system. This method is prone to abuse errors, etc., since my teacher did not want a log in system. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Would an array system work? make it so it checks the .dat file against the email, to see if they posted before?